# Is there any field in which applicants to PhD programs (in any part of the world) usually have publications?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions

We get occasional questions here from people who are applying to PhD programs, and are worried because they have no publications. This is puzzling to me, because most of my friends in PhD programs did not have any publications when they applied.

We've also previous agreed that it is not generally [*mandatory* to have a publication when applying to PhD](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11825/is-it-mandatory-to-have-published-papers-while-applying-for-phd), although it certainly helps. I am interested in knowing if there are *any* fields that are exceptions to this rule.

Are there any fields of study where (in some parts of the world, at least) most students have publications already by the time they apply for PhD admissions?

By "most," I mean that publications are common enough that a lack of one is seen as worrying, and possibly indicative of some deficiency in the applicant.

Comment: By the time I will apply for a neuroscience PhD, I will have published around five or six papers (mid-tier venues). Perhaps it sounds weird, but I feel having no chances of being hired to any top department.

Comment: @mmh Is that standard in neuroscience?

Comment: Just anecdotal evidence. I think most students have at least one paper in preparation/submitted/accepted related to their master's when applying. I'm in Europe.

Comment: It seems to be cultural. I may be wrong but it seems to me that US undergrads/master students have lot of free time and are expected to produce something of value on the side. Here in France you are not expected at all to publish anything in Math until after your M2. The courseload is expected to fill your time and only the most brilliant of all students sometimes publish tiny things.

Comment: In software engineering in central Europe, having a reasonable paper before starting your PhD is uncommon enough to be considered a *very* good thing to have. So no, it's certainly not common or expected.

Comment: Not confident enough to leave an answer, but: I suspect that the expectation of publications is stronger in Europe than in the US.  In Europe: (i) the undergraduate degree is more specialized; in some places and programs it is more similar to the beginning of a US graduate program than a US undergraduate program, whereas many US university students do not study X, they major in it, often taking less than half of their courses in that subject.  (ii) It is common to mandatory to do a separate master's program. So European PhD applicants may have the equivalent of 3-4 more years of training.

Comment: In Germany, as far as my (German) spouse knows, all Masters programs require a thesis.

Comment: Related: [What percentage of admitted phd students have peer-reviewed publications?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12885/what-percentage-of-admitted-phd-students-have-peer-reviewed-publications)

Comment: @aparente001: Bachelor and Master programs in Germany usually end with a thesis, yes, but that's not usually published in any way comparable to a paper, and the absolute expectation of a *scientific contribution* therein is debatable.

Comment: I know this is different, but many neuroscience/psych/cognitive science masters programs in Canada require a thesis from your undergrad, although it does not need to be published.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to make clear whether you're asking about having published something, or having published something peer reviewed.

Answer (score 5):

I'll point toward the Max Planck School for Computer Science,
[IMPRS-CS](http://www.imprs-cs.de/overview/phd/application.html), if I remember correctly they used to have even stronger wording than the current

> A successful candidate must...  have performed research and published (or submitted for publication) the results

But the MPIs are not the norm. Mostly, you would be fine with just your Masters thesis in math, comp sci, biology, or chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve been a part of a PhD admissions committee for a top school in the US in a field of engineering.  Expectations change based on your educational background.

The lack of any accepted/submitted/in process publications is a significant weakness in any applicants that hold an MS.  It is generally expected that during this time you were performing research, and its quality was sufficient for a peer reviewed conference or journal.

In undergraduate applicants who are applying directly to the PhD program, the lack of publications is not worrying whatsoever.  There is generally little opportunity or time for them to be produced.

As has been said elsewhere, applicants are ultimately judged on their ability or potential ability to perform self-driven, impactful research.  An undergraduate who has clearly made good use of their available time (summer internships involving research, extracurricular activities in the sciences, etc.) with no publications will most likely be viewed as a better candidate than an applicant with an MS with no publications.  An MS alone in this context is at best evidence of more successfully completed coursework, which is not what committees are looking for. At worst it can suggest deficiencies exist in their research ability.

Comment: "It is generally expected that during [Master studies] you were performing research." - could you add a note about the rough geographic area where this applies? For instance, in Germany, depending on the field, Master students rarely do research; they attend classes, participate in lab sessions and projects, and take exams, just like during their Bachelor studies, but with an increase in depth and difficulty of topics.

Comment: This answer is consistent with my experience in computer science in the US.

Comment: In the US there are typically two options for Master studies: course-work only, and thesis track.  The latter involves a research project (and a written thesis).

Comment: In addendum: In the case of, for example, an applicant with a German MS to a US PhD program, the organization of their typical MS program will likely be considered - but they will very possibly still sit at a disadvantage to their peers with MS publications.  Evidence of research ability remains the most important applicant criteria.

Answer (score 3):

For the context, I'm a Canadian doing a PhD in Biology.

In my University and for most Québec (Canadian?) universities, PhD applicant usually have a publication under way, whether it is published, accepted, submitted or in preparation.

The reason why is that most student have completed a master degree before. Altought publication is usually not mandatory in master degrees, it's becoming the norm.

I would dare say that this answer could fit countries and faculties/department where a master degree is required.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any rough numbers? (Look at the ten people sitting closest to you, how many of them had a publication underway when they applied?)

Comment: Hum...all? OK, probably 9/10, accounting for student from foreing countries who didn't do masters. However, some of those publications might take a long time to get accepted and really published. So the student will have it on his cv during his PhD. I would like very much if someone with the same background could back me up or not. It's a question hard to answered unbiaised.

Comment: "I would dare say that this answer could fit countries (...) where a master degree is required." - wouldn't this only be a valid assumptions for research-based Master degrees (as opposed to, say, coursework-only Master degrees)?

Answer (score 0):

In most subfields of computer science, most strong applicants will usually have some sort of publication record, usually with one work under submission/review at the time of application. First authorship is usually not common, though.

Comment: Perhaps you can give some context, and some numbers to support your assertion. Have you served on a PhD admissions committee in computer science? If not, on what do you base this answer?

Comment: This is based mostly on my experience as an applicant this past year, and the context is the traditional top four: Stanford, UCB, MIT, CMU.